# FileStream.Write Upload a image, but damaged or corrupted

Tags: asp.net, file-io, upload

hi I use FileStream to upload a file to web server, I am using asp.net, the upload works fine when I use Chrome or Firefox, but when I use IE, the file is damaged or corrupted, I could not open it.
here is the code

```
 try
   {

            using (fileStream = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                var length = 4096;
                var bytesRead = 0;
                var buffer = new Byte[length];
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                } while (bytesRead > 0);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            result = "{\"success\":\"false\"}";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fileStream != null)

                fileStream.Close();
        }
```

I already debugged, everything is fine, no exception, file could be save in the server, but just i could not open it? Any help, thanks so much

Comment: I found out the answer, I used valums Ajax Jquery add-on to upload file, because it does not need Flash on Brower, have a look here http://valums.com/ajax-upload/,

so when using firefox and chrome, the file stream is inside the Request.InputStream, but when using IE, the stream is inside the Request.Files[0].InputStream. That is why I could not save the image file correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the files... Use a tool like winmerge to look and see specifically what is different between the files being uploaded and saved.

once you see the difference you might be able to correct the condition.  For example it could be that IE is sending an extra byte at the end of the file... that is making it appear corrupt and you can just chop that off based on the user-agent...

GL

Comment: I found out the answer, I used

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code after flushing the file

```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```